# html and css tags, making fix nav top background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am really new to programing in HTML and I am trying to use bootstrap. However I cannot find a way to make navbar-fixed-top background color white. I tried adding it in navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top, nothing helps.

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Viverius, Institute for development of digital health </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">O nas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Projekti</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Ekipa</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: HTML is document markup, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below `css` code in a new `css file` called `style.css` or whatever name you want and place this file just after the `bootstrap css` file to override the default bootstrap css in your `<head>` tag like this:

**CSS Code(In style.css)**

```
.navbar-default {
   background: #fff;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default{
    background:#fff;
}
```

This should work. Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/3kz1ssbn/)

Make sure you are loading your custom css after bootstraps css that way your custom css will override bootstraps css.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d86bLyjx/)

You have to put custom css after including bootstrap css file. CSS I write:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Works as you wanted to work.